# Updating path openssl keeps using wrong path

Tags: macos, path, openssl

I had to downgrade openssl version for mysql. But when I ran `openssl version` I still got the wrong version. So I checked `which openssl` and I saw that it's using from anaconda:

```
(base) ➜  ~ which openssl
/opt/anaconda3/bin/openssl
```

But it needs to use:

```
(base) ➜  ~ ls /usr/local/Cellar/openssl
1.0.2t
```

So **what I tried**:

```
(base) ➜  ~ export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/bin:$PATH"
(base) ➜  ~ source ~/.bash_profile
(base) ➜  ~ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/bin
/opt/anaconda3/bin
/opt/anaconda3/condabin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

So as you can see, my path is updated correctly. But when I run again `which openssl` it still gives me openssl from anaconda, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I would worry about using two package managers at one conda and homebrew. Can you use just conda. This might also sort out version ng issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/bin` (which currently is in your PATH) doesn't exist. If you want to use `openssl` from Homebrew use `/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin` (which will always point to the latest version installed via Homebrew).

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH“
```

Comment: Is it just the path you defined, or do I have to add `/bin:$PATH`?

Comment: @zal Not sure I understand. Repeat what you did, but use the path with `opt` in it instead of the one with `Cellar`.